# Executing multiple SQL statements with Database class

Tags: add-on-development, database, mysql

Using `$this->EE->db->query();` is it possible to execute a query as complicated as this:

```
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE exp_temp_table (...);
INSERT INTO exp_temp_table () SELECT ...;
UPDATE exp_temp_table ... SET ...;
SELECT ... FROM exp_temp_table ...;
```

For obvious reasons I've removed most of the actual statements.

This code executes perfectly in phpMyAdmin, but when I try to use `$this->EE->db->query();` I get a SQL error at `INSERT INTO exp_temp_table ()...` - is it not possible to execute queries with multiple statements? If not, is there some way I can work around this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was worried about the temporary table not persisting between queries but the following code worked correctly:

```
$this->EE->db->query('CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE exp_temp_table (...)');
$this->EE->db->query('INSERT INTO exp_temp_table () SELECT ...');
$this->EE->db->query('UPDATE exp_temp_table ... SET ...');
$query = $this->EE->db->query('SELECT ... FROM exp_temp_table ...');
```

Answer (score 1):

I think, you should run queries via Transactions. You can find the doc from CodeIgnitor's user guide http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/database/transactions.html and it also works within EE.

Comment: An excellent point thanks for mentioning.